# OneDrive for Business API issues on Discovery and Authorization

Tags: azure, sharepoint, office365, onedrive

I've been trying to implement OneDrive Business API according to this [OneDrive Release Notes](https://dev.onedrive.com/odb-preview/release-notes.htm). We've already implemented OneDrive end users API without any issue.

First obvious thing to do is to handle OAuth2 authentication to get right tokens, first to discover {tenant}-my.sharepoint.com specific Tenant OneDrive Business URI and after that get tokens for that tenant. Documenation for that purpose could be found [here](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm).

Following that tutorial we have been able to do the following:

1. Register the App in Azure AD. **Done**
2. Sign into OneDrive for Business

   - Log in and get an authorization code. **Done**
   - Redeem the authorization code for tokens. **Done**
   - Discover the OneDrive for Business resource URI. **FAIL**
   - Redeem refresh token for an access token to call OneDrive API. **Done**
   - Make a request to the OneDrive API. **FAIL**

It can be appreciated, we had issues on step 2, ***Discover the OneDrive for Business resource URI*** and ***Make a request to the OneDrive API***.

#### Issue on Discover the OneDrive for Business resource URI

The problem with this part of the process is, although we are hitting to **api.office.com/discovery/v2.0/me/services** with the first **Access Token** obtained after redeem with resource **api.office.com/discovery/**, we are not getting in the list of services tenant specific sharepoint URI for OneDrive for Business. Any entry in the list we are getting come with `capability = "MyFiles" AND serviceApiVersion = "v2.0"` according documentation. In fact any entry in the list has the structure {tenant}-my.sharepoint.com in serviceEndpointUri. This is JSON response i am getting back. I removed some of the sensitive data:

```
{
"@odata.context" : "https://api.office.com/discovery/v2.0/me/$metadata#allServices",
"value" : [ {
  "capability" : "Directory",
  "providerName" : "Microsoft",
  "serviceAccountType" : 2,
  "serviceApiVersion" : "",
  "serviceEndpointUri" : "http://azure.microsoft.com/",
  "serviceName" : "Microsoft Azure",
  "serviceResourceId" : null
}, {
  "capability" : "MyFiles",
  "providerName" : "Microsoft",
  "serviceAccountType" : 2,
  "serviceApiVersion" : "",
  "serviceEndpointUri" : "http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/online-software.aspx",
  "serviceName" : "Office 365 SharePoint",
  "serviceResourceId" : null
}, {
  "capability" : "RootSite",
  "providerName" : "Microsoft",
  "serviceAccountType" : 2,
  "serviceApiVersion" : "",
  "serviceEndpointUri" : "http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/online-software.aspx",
  "serviceId" : "O365_SHAREPOINT",
  "serviceName" : "Office 365 SharePoint",
  "serviceResourceId" : null
}, {
  "capability" : "MyFiles",
  "providerName" : "Microsoft",
  "serviceAccountType" : 1,
  "serviceApiVersion" : "",
  "serviceEndpointUri" : "https://g.live.com/8seskydrive/HomePageUrl",
  "serviceName" : "OneDrive",
  "serviceResourceId" : null
} ]
}
```

The problem with this is if i logged in to my portal.office.com and check my sharepoint urls, it is well configured and i can see {tenant}-my.sharepoint.com URI.

#### Issue on Make a request to the OneDrive API

Apart i am not able to discovery correct **tenant sharepoint URI**, if i hardcode the URL to redeem next **Access Token** request with my **tenant sharepoint URI**, I am getting an access token but when i want to make a call for example to `https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/drive/root` or any other endpoint i am getting 401 Unauthorize response in every call, even when the token has just been acquired. Here is a handshake example. I am hiding sensitive data:

```
curl -v 'https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/drives' -H 'Authorization:   Bearer TOKEN_ACQUIRED'
Connected to {tenant}-my.sharepoint.com port 443
GET /drives HTTP/1.1
Host: {tenant}-my.sharepoint.com
Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_ACQUIRED

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

Could you advice me with this? Is there some configuration missing in my tenant? Is there some configuration missing in my Azure AD App?

BTW, permissions scope on my App i am getting in every redeem are `AllSites.FullControl AllSites.Manage MyFiles.Write Sites.Search.All TermStore.ReadWrite.All User.Read.All`. I think i have permissions properly set.

Best,

List item

Comment: Can you confirm that response from the discovery service was for /services and not /allServices?

Comment: Never mind, apparently querying "/services" returns an @odata.context for "allServices"... that's a little strange.

Comment: How did you acquire the access token to call the discovery service?  The Discovery service itself is returning service info objects for both Active Directory accounts and Microsoft Accounts (serviceAccountType : 1 means MSA and 2 means Active Directory.  What platform are you on?  If you are iOS, .net or Andriod the OneDriveSDKs will handle all of this for you

Comment: We are developing our own implementation written in Java. It is a backend Application

Comment: Hi aclev, we acquire access token according OneDrive for Business documentation API here https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm. Apart from that the user which i am authenticating here is an User with a Enterprise License E3 and if i logged in with this user to portal Office 365 i am seeing OneDrive for Business activated. In fact i could access OneDrive for Business in this user going to https://{mytenant}-my.sharepoint.com/persona/{user}

Comment: Any thoughts on What i am doing wrong?

Comment: what was the resource you used to get the access token?(in 2nd step while redeeming the access token from authorization code.)

Comment: I have tried the same procedure in the [documentation](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm) and worked perfectly.                                            In fact the api endpoint to get drives is **https://<teanantname>-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/me/drive**. the resource from the access token should be matched to the endpoint .

Comment: Hi Juan, was you be able to solve this problem? Discovery service return no results if I call https://api.office.com/discovery/v2.0/me/services. It's just empty. But when I hardcoded resource uri, i was able to list drive content.

Comment: Is it possible to make discovery service work? Thanks for any help

Comment: Discovery service always return following response for me: {"@odata.context":"https://api.office.com/discovery/v1.0/me/$metadata#allServices","value":[]}

Answer (score -1):

Might be a bit late, but this [blog article](https://cloudrail.com/connect-onedrive-onedrive-for-business-api/) addresses how to use the OneDrive API and OneDrive for Business API exactly the same. 
Here is a quick Java code snippet:

```
CloudRail.setAppKey("[CloudRail License Key]");

// CloudStorage cs = new OneDrive(redirectReceiver, "[clientIdentifier]", "[clientSecret]", "[redirectUri]", "[state]");
CloudStorage cs = new OneDriveBusiness(redirectReceiver, "[clientID]", "[clientSecret]", "[redirectUri]", "[state]");

new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        cs.createFolder("/TestFolder");
        InputStream stream = null;
        try {
            stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("Data.csv");
            long size = new File(getClass().getResource("Data.csv").toURI()).length();
            cs.upload("/TestFolder/Data.csv", stream, size, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle error
        } finally {
            // TODO: close stream
        }
    }
}.start();
```